# How can I code to search across multiple columns within a group - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have cancer data and each patient had 1-4 measurements.  Some measurements had cytology done, others had pathology done, some had both.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

data<-tribble(
  ~record_number, ~tool, ~cytology, ~pathology,
  114, "forceps", "Indeterminate", NA,
  114, "needle", "Non-Malignant", "Malignant",
  114, "lavage", NA, "Indeterminate",
  115, "forceps", NA, "Non-Malignant",
  115, "needle", NA, "Malignant"
)
```

I'd like to create a Malignancy variable (0/1) if "Malignant" occurs for any of the samples (rows) for a given subject (record_number), in *either* of the columns (cytology, pathology).

Any ideas are appreciated!

```
desired<-tribble(
  ~record_number, ~tool, ~cytology, ~pathology, ~ Malignant,
  114, "forceps", "Indeterminate", NA, 1,
  114, "needle", "Non-Malignant", "Malignant", 1,
  114, "lavage", NA, "Indeterminate", 1, 
  115, "forceps", NA, "Non-Malignant", 1, 
  115, "needle", NA, "Malignant", 1,
)
```

I'm thinking it will start with group_by(record_number)...but then what?

```
desired<-data %>%
  group_by(record_number) %>%
  ...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `ifelse` with `any`:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0

data %>%
  mutate(Malignant = ifelse(any(cytology == "Malignant" | pathology == "Malignant", na.rm = TRUE), 1, 0), .by=record_number)

  record_number tool    cytology      pathology     Malignant
          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
1           114 forceps Indeterminate NA                    1
2           114 needle  Non-Malignant Malignant             1
3           114 lavage  NA            Indeterminate         1
4           115 forceps NA            Non-Malignant         1
5           115 needle  NA            Malignant             1
```

Comment: Thanks, TarJae!  Needed one edit - added na.rm=TRUE to the any argument.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(Malignant = as.numeric(any(c(cytology, pathology) == 'Malignant', na.rm = TRUE)), .by = record_number)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  record_number tool    cytology      pathology     Malignant
          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
1           114 forceps Indeterminate <NA>                  1
2           114 needle  Non-Malignant Malignant             1
3           114 lavage  <NA>          Indeterminate         1
4           115 forceps <NA>          Non-Malignant         1
5           115 needle  <NA>          Malignant             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%in%` operator for this too which will not return `NA` if there are NAs:

```
data |>
  mutate(malignancy = 1*("Malignant" %in% c(cytology, pathology)), .by = record_number)
```

**Output**

```
  record_number tool    cytology      pathology     malignancy
1           114 forceps Indeterminate NA                     1
2           114 needle  Non-Malignant Malignant              1
3           114 lavage  NA            Indeterminate          1
4           115 forceps NA            Non-Malignant          1
5           115 needle  NA            Malignant              1
```